# Algolia: Get Additional Facet Details

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, facet, algolia

I am trying to build an iOS app to query and list some objects to browse instead/in-addition to directly searching or refining over an index that i have in algolia.

when i execute the query with the general parameters and no facet filtering , all works fine and i get all my objects in the **hits** node, and i get a **facets** node too, with the name of the facet and a number signifying the number of hits that carry this facet.

***TLDR: Can I modify the facets node of the query response to have additional data, ex: Image URLs?***

I can easily show the refining options user has, like facet and the number of hits under that facet, But what if I want to show additional data , such as an image against each facet ?

Basically if i have a single tableView or collectionView now, showing all the hits , I want to modify that so I can present the user with categorised data.

like multiple tableViews or multiple collection View or even complex UI such as A tableView where each row has a collectionView, depending on the facets and each cell has an image.

is that possible?

Comment: Answered on [discourse](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/ios-get-additional-facet-details/3248)

Comment: Yeah, got your reply. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Anytime man. Feel free to give us feedback on our libraries, and ask for new features as well!

Comment: hello @KinshukKashyap i am also trying to implement Instant search i.e. algolia but here i am passing categories id to display and filter the result to display in list page and here i am using facet filters to filter from facets array can u please help me to resolve this ?

Comment: hello @KinshukKashyap i had filtered the data by passing selected id from categories page to list page and got filtered data response but unable to pass to hit and display in collection view if u know bro please help me i was trying from lot more days

Comment: Hey Vamsi can you please provide your Query Code, and the Delegate/DataSource Code